# Selenium c#: How to get the Id attribute?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to get the id from the following code:

[image]

**This id is generating dynamically, can be different each times.**

The Xpath looks as below:

```
//*[@id="chart_9"]
```

The Xpath from one line above is following:

```
//*[@id="TransientResponse_tab"]/div[2]/div/div[2]
```

The problem is that I can't get the id - I have tried in different ways, e.g.:

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("chartContainer")).GetAttribute("id");
```

It also doesn't work.

Can you give some tips how I can struggle with it?

Comment: what exception did you get?

Comment: did you tried using `WebDriverWait` to wait until it's visible??

Comment: I think your xpath expression is wrong, should it be `//*[@id="TransientResponse_tab"]/div[2]/div/div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it in more ways:

```
String text = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[class='chartContainer']")).GetAttribute("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
String s1 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.chartContainer")).GetAttribute("id");
```

Hope this helps.